# How to supress a string field in crystal report if text size exceeded field bounds?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I've a string field in my crystal report that show certain string data that must be shown as a whole from first char to last char and i can't predict maximum length of this string.Is there a way to suppress this field or to show warning message in this field if string in it exceeds the bounds ? Please notice that i don't want to use text wrapping in this field

Comment: Does the field have a maximum length?  What is the maximum length in the current data?  What is the likely maximum?  Does your database allow you to calculate the length of the data?  Which version of CR?  Have you tested to see what length will result in CR truncating the field?

Comment: Do you mean number of characters or actual pixel length?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, Crystal Reports doesn't have any functionality to determine the width of a string, taking font type into account.

Off the top of my head, your best bet would be to use a fixed-width font, and then suppress the field if the string has more than X characters (X being however many characters it would take for the string to exceed the bounds of the field).

If you're not using, or can't/won't use a fixed-width font, you might be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

- Determine at what length Crystal Reports will truncate the field
- Calculate the length of the field (in a separate column) and include this in the dataset (or do so in a SQL Expression field)
- Either suppress the field or the section that contains it if the length field is >= the maximum value